# How to get user list from any Local User Group dynamically? I am trying below code but its not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, echo

```
@Echo Off

:Start

Echo This will show Users belonging to any User Group

Echo.

Echo Please Select Local Group from below list

Pause

net localgroup

SET /P GroupName = Enter Group Name 

Echo %GroupName%

pause 

net localgroup %GroupName%

pause

CLS

GoTo Start
```

Comment: Remove the spaces. `SET /P GroupName=Enter Group Name`

Comment: @npocmaka Thank you for this. It is working now. I read that somewhere but couldn't collect that while writing. Thanks again.